# ! + enter, doesn't work, vs codeJune 2022 (version 1.69) update , HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, shortcut

After the new VS Code update, I'm not able to use ! + enter to do my base code automatically anymore. The onyl change was the new update and I also opened up a new Git repository and ignored the vs code folder. After that, I also can't use ! + enter in any other html-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type html and then choose this

```
html:5
```

and click enter this will create the code

Answer (score 0):

Try ! + Tab or !!! + Tab

Reply if it works